# WinRT: RenderAsync Blurs Image Output

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have kinda a unique case when making use of the `RenderAsync` method on the `RenderTargetBitmap` class. The thing is when I run the code (that can be seen below) on my laptop it works just fine and the image renders correctly. But when I run the code on my Lenovo tablet, it blurs the image.

Code being used:

```
var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(element, (int) element.Width, (int) element.Height);
var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
    var bytes = pixels.ToArray();
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint) element.ActualWidth, (uint) element.ActualHeight, 300, 300, bytes);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
}
```

This is how the original image looks like and how it's being rendered on my laptop:

[image]

This is how it looks on my tablet after the exact same code has been ran:

[image]

Could someone please provide some assistance?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was pretty simple. Just change the following piece of code and make use of `renderTargetBitmap` instead of `element`

```
encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight, 300, 300, bytes);
```